# Wpf Command Binding to ViewModel or Model?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a several models and a TreeView to display them. The HierarchicalDataTemplate displays the Models using ItemsSource.
Ruff outline...

```
public class ModelA : ObservableBase
{
  private string _name = "A";
  private Observablecollection<ModelB>_bModels = new Observablecollection<ModelB>();

  String Name {
    get {return _name;}
    set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"}}
  Observablecollection<ModelB>BModels {
    get {retun __bModels; }
    set {_bModels = value; OnPropertyChanged("BModels"}}
}

ModelB is similar.
```

Now the TreeView displays the data correctly and I have added ContextMenus to each level. Initially on a TextBlock.ContextMenu within the HierarchicalData but now as a Resource in the TreeView.Resource.

The commands now call CommandProperties within each Model which is great IF it is the way it should be done BUT it does have a problem with one command which needed to call a CommandProperty from either the other Model or the ViewModel.
I have set it to the ViewModel and it works but I now have commands all over the place.

The question is therefore where should the Commands go ? In the Model they belong to and/or in the ViewModel ?

Commands are "Add A", "Remove A", "Add B", "Remove B"

```
Root- Add A
A- Add B/Remove A (this)
  B- Remove B
  B- Remove B
A- Add B/Remove A (this)
  B- Remove B
```

I would show more code if required but it will take up a lot of space, Hopefully you can understand the concept and problem from this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all bindings should be resolved between the View and the ViewModel. Model should be used just to provide data for ViewModel, from which should it be exposed for the View to display via binding.

The structure of the MVVM application should look more or less like this:

- **Model** - stores data (possibly have some basic data operations implemented, such as calculations)
- **ViewModel** - has implementation of all operations done by the View on the data. For example if you delete row from your DataGrid, your ViewModel should have a command for it, which implements call for method from either Model or some additional layer of your application, that will perform required actions (but ViewModel should not operate on data itself). A ViewModel should also get data from Model and expose it as properties bound with a View in order to display data.
- **View** - provides a user interface to allow user perform actions. It should not implement any actions other than related to displaying things (even in code behind). For example event that binds data in code behind should be prohibited to follow MVVM pattern, but action for switching color of the button when it is clicked can be done either in code behind or in ViewModel (depending on personal preferences), since it's only View related.
- ***Data operations layer*** - it's pretty common yet optional to use additional layer to manage data operations performed on Model.

Comment: I can understand this but I watched a video of someone explaining that if all you are doing is exposing the data via accessors with a ViewModel then don't bother with the ViewModel and just do it from the Model.

Also, the way the Hierachical data structure works on a treeview doesn't lend itself to using View Models without duplicating your whole model structure.

Comment: the info you watched in the video isnt wrong. But it depends on the situation. Design patterns are there to make your life easier (and easier for others you work with), if for some reason it does not make things easier, then change it or go a different route. If you have to triple your code to make the viewmodel work, well it would seem like you may want to fix something in the design.

Comment: Generics and Reflection can also be your friend when exposing your models via ViewModels.

Comment: What I described is the pure MVVM structure in it's original form. There are many "code wizards" that will say that this or that can be done easier or in a different way. They are mostly right, but for me, a design pattern is something you should stick to, if you decide to use it. Otherwise what is the reason to use it at the first place?

Comment: Also as Ginger Ninja said, everything depends on the situation, and on the project and the team size. If it's a solo project, you can do whatever you want since it will be your responsibility to work on that code and to maintain it. If it's a big project with team of +3 developers, I'd suggest sticking strictly to the design pattern you decide to implement, because you may end up in the situation where your team would blame you for taking shortcuts.

Comment: I have had a situation in my previous team, where one guy decided to do something differently than in MVVM because he saw a tutorial and liked it. He left few months after that and we had to rewrite all of his code from scratch because noone wanted to work on it and everyone considered it as not maintainable. Basically 1 developer taking 1 shortcut made 1 functionality cost 3 times more than it should (1 estimate for his work, 1 for people investigating what is wrong, 1 for other developer who was rewriting his code). So as you can see, shortcuts are not always shortcuts in a long term...